# BackboneJS Uncaught ReferenceError: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbonejs I am able to add and show the contacts from database . but i am unable to execute a delete using backbonejs. JSFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/L183kw0o/10/
When i try to delete it gives me the error

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Id is not defined "
```

Below is the stacktrace
    (anonymous function) VM103:2
    InjectedScript._evaluateOn VM69:730
    InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap VM69:669
   InjectedScript.evaluate VM69:581

**This is My Model**

```
var modelContact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            Id: 0,
            Name: "",
            Address: ""
        };
    },
    idAttribute: "Id",
    url: function(){
        return 'api/Contact/' + this.get("Id");
    },
    initialize: function () {
        if (!this.get("Id")) {
            this.set({ "Id": this.defaults().Id });
        }
    },
    clear: function() {
        console.log(this.get("Id"));
        this.destroy({
            error: function(model, response) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function(model, response) {
                alert("success"); 
                console.log(response); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Model Collection**

```
var contactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: modelContact,
    url: function() {
        return 'api/Contact';
    }
});
var contacts = new contactCollection;
```

**View**

```
var contactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    events: {
        "click a.destroy": "clear"
    },
    template: _.template($("#newContacttemplate").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.remove, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        if (this.isGoingToBeRemoved) {
            return (this);
        }
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    clear: function (e) {
       this.isGoingToBeRemoved = true;
       this.model.clear();
    }
});
```

All errors are resolved this is the working code

Comment: Which version of Backbone do you use ?

Comment: You are overriding Backbone Model's `clear` [method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clear).

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle and show us how you create your model ?

Comment: The whole purpose of the `defaults` is so you don't do what you're doing in the initialize method. You can drop that altogether

Comment: @Maroshii yes I am am Overriding it and calling the destroy on it. okay But I Do not think dropping the default will solve the issue.

Comment: @KinnanNawaz dont do that!

Comment: Can you post the trace / error stack?

Comment: You can use "console.trace()" or "(new Error).stack" to display the stack.

Comment: below is the exception in console
Uncaught ReferenceError: Id is not defined VM27:6(anonymous function) VM27:6c underscore.min.js:5Backbone.View.extend.render ModelContact.js:37f backbone.js:208e.Events.trigger backbone.js:148i.extend.set backbone.js:368i.extend.clear backbone.js:386Backbone.View.extend.clear ModelContact.js:41x.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095v.handle

Comment: Stack Trace Using Console.trace()
(anonymous function) VM103:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn VM69:730InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap VM69:669InjectedScript.evaluate

Comment: JsFiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/L183kw0o/ the webapi is on local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from "render".

Indeed, You are setting a value and you erase your model :

```
    clears: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(this.model);
        this.model.set({ // trigger change
            Id: 3
        });
        this.model.get("Id");
        this.model.clear(); // remove your model
    }
```

Because, JS is asynchronous, you will have "render" and "clear" called in same time. And when you will call `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` the model.get('Id') will be already removed.. So, you will try to call something that doesn't exist

```
render: function () {
    // console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); // this.model.toJSON() == {}
    return this;
},
```

You have to prevent the render method when you "clear" your model.

Comment: removed Kindly check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ssgexu1y/
in the clears function i have removed all the code except 
this.model.clear();// But same error :(

Comment: okay this fiddle has definitely removed the error but my changes are not posted back to the server. now i do not receive any error. but changes are not posted to the server.

Comment: Do you have "this.destroy();" in your method "clear" ?

Comment: yes i have in the model . it was not before
   clear: function() {
            this.destroy();
        } dubuging y it is not going to the server

Comment: Do you use the success and error options ? (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63116/discussion-between-queval-j-and-kinnan-nawaz).